# Exposing different "views" of the same model

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Often you create webservices and you use many different technologies. For instance som may take a pojo annotated with some annotations from some other framework such as Jackson. However, I would like to have different views/versions of the model. I do not always want to expose everything, or other times I need other annotations on the same field. I know Jackson have Views, but Jackson is Only an example.

Are there any patterns for this. Or am I doing the right thing when I create for instance a Car class which is the "real" model and then create CarExport, IndexedCar etc that use some of the car model data but have different annotations and may have other properties too?

Sometimes the model need another structure/organization to put it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to take a look at the [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) or [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

> The intention is to abstract steps of construction of objects so that
>   different implementations of these steps can construct different
>   representations of objects. Often, the builder pattern is used to
>   build products in accordance with the composite pattern.

Comment: That would not help if you need to add different annotations for instance.